# How can I use numeric up down to retrive datagridview inserted result or past data inserted to datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

How can I use a numeric up down control to retrive datagridview inserted result or past data inserted to datagridview?

```
LoadRec = DbSelect("Select * from tblInvoiceDetails  where InvoiceNo= " & No & "")
If LoadRec.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    NumericUpDown1.Value = LoadRec.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
    DataGridView2.DataSource = DbSelect("Select * from tblInvoiceDetails.itemno , ItemName, Qt, Price, Total   where InvoiceNo= " & No & "")
```

Comment: Are you saying: You have a database table named `tblInvoiceDetails`. When the invoice details are selected for an `InvoiceNo`, you want to be able to move through the items for that particular invoice by using a NumericUpDown control?

Comment: yes typically @AndrewMorton

Comment: 1) Which database software does it use? 2) Is `itemno` strictly ascending, like 1,2,3,4 etc. or could there be gaps, like 1,2,4,5?

Comment: sql server 2014 @AndrewMorton

Comment: I posted an answer, but I really did need an answer to the second question in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to react to the value of the NumericUpDown control changing.

I will assume that the values of `itemno` are strictly 1,2,3,4 etc. If not, the SQL query would have to be different.

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    Dim n = DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown).Value

    'TODO: Set invoiceNo to the correct value
    Dim invoiceNo As Integer = 1
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Dim sql = "SELECT [ItemName], [Qt], [Price], [Total] FROM [tblInvoiceDetails] WHERE [InvoiceNo] = @InvoiceNo AND [itemno] = @itemno"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("your connection string"),
            sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@InvoiceNo", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = invoiceNo})
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@itemno", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = n})

        Dim dr As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        dr.Fill(dt)

    End Using

    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

The line

```
NumericUpDown1.Value = LoadRec.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
```

should probably be

```
NumericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(LoadRec.Rows(0).Item(0))
NumericUpDown1.Maximum = LoadRec.Rows.Count
```

It would be a good idea to add an overload of the method `DbSelect` which takes an [SqlParameterCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection). It is a bad idea to concatenate values into the query as is currently being done.